# Ordinary Differentiation $t^2y''=t(t+2)y'-(t+2)y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
t^2y''=t(t+2)y'-(t+2)y
$$

The question is how to find the Wronskian without knowing the solutions of this equation?

I uploaded the origin question below, which is from a sample test.

Anyone could help me? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

If $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ are two solutions of:

$$y''(t) + p(t) y'(t) + q(t) y = 0$$

Then the Wronskian is given by:

$$W(y_1,y_2)(t) = ce^{-\int p(t)~dt}$$

Where:

$$p(t) = -\dfrac{t(t+2)}{t^2}$$

Comment: Oh yeah, I got it, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Note: this is known as [Abel's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity).